# How do you prove the following solutions to these summation problems?

Tags: calculus

I'm having such a difficult time with finding patterns and solving summation problems in general. I have no idea how to prove the solutions to the following problems:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(i+1)(i+2)=\frac{n(n^2+6n+11)}{3}$$
Edit: #1 is solved.
$$\sum\limits_{i=3}^{99}(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i+1})=\frac{97}{300}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2}{n}[(\frac{2i}{n})^3+5(\frac{2i}{n})]=14$$

The most difficult thing for me is trying to find the pattern and coming up with a general equation. Any help, advice, and tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: In addition to the properties mentioned in SiongThyeGoh's answer below, I would point out that (*at least for finite sums*) you have the property that summations are [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) in the sense that for $f,g$ functions on $\Bbb N$ and $\alpha,\beta$ constants, you have $\sum_n \left(\alpha f(n) + \beta g(n)\right) = \alpha \sum_n f(n) + \beta \sum_n g(n)$, so for your first example for instance you have $\sum_{i=1}^n (i+1)(i+2) = \sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+3i+2) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + 3\sum_{i=1}^n i + 2\sum_{i=1}^n 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the formulae to the formulae Siong Thye Goh provided for the first and third sum. These are simple to prove by induction, if necessary.

For the second sum, notice that the $k$th bracket is $(\frac 1k - \frac{1}{k+1})$ while the $k+1$th bracket is $(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2})$. Summing these, the $\frac{1}{k+1}$ vanishes, and most of the terms will. Find which terms don't cancel, and evaluate the sum from there. (This is what is known as a telescoping sum)

---

Explanation of telescoping sum for this question:

We are trying to evaluate:

$$\sum_{i=3}^{99}(\frac 1i - \frac{1}{i+1})$$
When $i=3$, we have $(\frac 13 - \frac 14)$

When $i=4$ we have $(\frac 14 - \frac 15)$

When $i=5$ we have $(\frac 15- \frac 16)$

etc

When $i=97$ we have $(\frac{1}{97} -\frac{1}{98})$

When $i=98$ we have $(\frac{1}{98} -\frac{1}{99})$

When $i=99$ we have $(\frac{1}{99} -\frac{1}{100})$

Notice in the first two terms we have $\frac 13 -\frac14 +\frac14 -\frac 15$.

It's quite easy to see that the $\frac 14$s cancel, leaving $\frac13-\frac15$. But then, the $\frac15$ is cancelled by the next term. In other words, the only starting term that remains is the $\frac13$.

Looking at the end, the $\frac{1}{97}$ will cancel with the term before it (check when $i=96$ to see this), and the $\frac{1}{98}$ and $\frac{1}{99}$ clearly cancel. This means the only end term left is the $-\frac{1}{100}$.

The sum therefore amounts to $$\frac 13 - \frac{1}{100}=\frac{99}{300}$$

Comment: Do you know how to solve this with only induction? I have not heard/learned about telescoping sum yet

Comment: It's not a difficult concept to grasp, so I've outlined it for you by extending my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ingredients that you need:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$

- The idea of telescoping sum.
- Perhaps the idea of Riemann sum might help as well.